# No Wi-Fi adapter found QCA9565/AR9565

Tags: wireless, 18.04

I tried so many ways on google, youtube and other people questions on here but didn't work, my wifi was working fine. Last time after a reboot my wifi stopped working, trying to restart network manager doesn't do the trick, my settings showing me "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" , trying `lshw -class network` shows me the following:

```
    root@user:/home/dnory0# lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: ec:f4:bb:7b:68:ed
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0700000-c0700fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 54:35:30:4e:2d:4f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-38-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:c0600000-c067ffff memory:c0680000-c068ffff
root@user:/home/dnory0# lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] [1002:6660] (rev ff)
```

I read an article that qualcomm cards are compatible with ubuntu 18.04 due to dell support, so what could be the problem?
I'm using ubuntu for 2 months and this is new to me.

Comment: It shows as disable so perhaps you disabled it with the hardware switch? Or at BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: To be more specific I use a dell laptop, so no hardware switch, but about at bios/uefi might be right cause I have dual boot to windows 10, the wifi iss not working either, even though I didn't access my bios for a long time, is there a way that it disactivated automatically?

Comment: I never saw *any* laptop without a hardware switch due to power saving considerations. It is often called Airplane Mode. Please check again.

Comment: That  doesn't usually happen but it's possible. However, it not working also in Windows is concerning and **it should have been posted in the question**. In a dual-boot, if it works in one but not the other, we are looking for software causes but if doesn't work in both then we're looking at hardware or BIOS/UEFI settings. This includes a toggle key (F12 or other or FN+something). Please check your user's manual or

Comment: Sorry for the misundertand, I do have airplane mode and it's off for both sysrems. **about BIOS** it didn't seems to have any networking option so I set bios to default setting but still the problem same, windows boots now automatically with airplane mode activated, and turning it off option is disactivated to me, is there a possibility my wifi card was dammaged, although bluetooth works on my pc and I guess bluetooth and wifi comes in one card so I'm not sure if it's hard or soft problem!

Comment: i am also having the same problem.. any help would be appreciated